# MySQL - check for empty result

Tags: mysql, sql

This query will return an empty *(not null, namely empty, like undefined)* result

```
SELECT value
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.id = 215 
AND t1.property_id = 2
```

This query will also return same result.

```
SELECT 
    IF( ISNULL(value) OR ISEMPTY(value) OR value = '', 0, 1 ) AS value 
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.id = 215 
AND t1.property_id = 2
```

How can I, instead of empty instead of empty value, paste some value in result?
Very important use only native mysql(5.6) tools.

Comment: Can you add the result layout you are getting on the first query and what would be the expected result. It will be clearer for us to understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If you are only looking for one result, you can use aggregation:

```
SELECT COALESCE(MAX(value), ?)
FROM table t1
WHERE t1.id = 215 AND t1.property_id = 2
```

The `?` is a placeholder for the value you want.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution 1:**   You can use case with condition, update Your_value as which you want

```
select CASE WHEN value IS NULL THEN  'Your_value' ELSE value END AS u_value 
FROM 
 table t1
WHERE t1.id = 215 
AND t1.property_id = 2;
```

It will give extract result which you want.

**Solution 2** : You can also this  **MySQL COALESCE()**  function returns the first non-NULL value of a list, or NULL if there are no non-NULL values.

```
SELECT coalesce(NULLIF(value, ''), 'Your_value')
FROM 
table t1
WHERE t1.id = 215 
AND t1.property_id = 2
```